# How can I move my params checkbox from react-router-dom to next js 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a React application that uses react-router-dom to manage URL parameters and checkboxes for filtering items. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSearchParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const sexData = [
  { value: "male", name: "Male" },
  { value: "female", name: "Female" },
];

const colorData = [
  { value: "red", name: "Red" },
  { value: "blue", name: "Blue" },
  { value: "green", name: "Green" },
];

const categoryData = [
  { value: "clothing", name: "Clothing" },
  { value: "shoes", name: "Shoes" },
  { value: "accessories", name: "Accessories" },
];

const sizeData = [
  { value: "small", name: "Small" },
  { value: "medium", name: "Medium" },
  { value: "large", name: "Large" },
];

export default function App() {
  const navigation = useNavigate();
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState(() => {
    const initialItems = {
      sex: {},
      colors: {},
      categories: {},
      size: {},
    };
    return initialItems;
  });

  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentParams = Object.fromEntries([...searchParams]);
    updateSelectedItems(currentParams);
  }, [searchParams]);

  const updateSelectedItems = (params) => {
    const newItems = { ...selectedItems };
    for (const key in newItems) {
      if (params[key]) {
        const itemList = params[key].split(",");
        newItems[key] = itemList.reduce((acc, item) => {
          acc[item] = true;
          return acc;
        }, {});
      }
    }
    setSelectedItems(newItems);
  };

  const handleOnChange = (group, value) => {
    const updatedItems = { ...selectedItems };
    if (!updatedItems[group][value]) {
      updatedItems[group][value] = true;
    } else {
      delete updatedItems[group][value];
    }
    setSelectedItems(updatedItems);

    // Update URL params
    const paramArray = [];
    for (const key in updatedItems) {
      const selectedItemsArray = Object.keys(updatedItems[key]);
      if (selectedItemsArray.length > 0) {
        const paramString = selectedItemsArray.join(",");
        paramArray.push(`${key}=${paramString}`);
      }
    }
    const queryParams = paramArray.join("&");
    navigation(`/?${queryParams}`);
  };

  const renderList = (group, title, data) => (
    <div className="item-group">
      <h3>Select {title}</h3>
      <ul className="item-list">
        {data.map(({ value, name }, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <div className="item-list-item">
              <div className="left-section">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id={`custom-checkbox-${group}-${index}`}
                  name={name}
                  value={value}
                  checked={selectedItems[group][value] || false}
                  onChange={() => handleOnChange(group, value)}
                />
                <label htmlFor={`custom-checkbox-${group}-${index}`}>{name}</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {renderList("sex", "Sex", sexData)}
      {renderList("colors", "Colors", colorData)}
      {renderList("categories", "Categories", categoryData)}
      {renderList("size", "Size", sizeData)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this code, I have checkboxes that allow users to filter items based on various criteria (e.g., sex, colors, categories, size). These checkboxes update the URL parameters to reflect the user's selections, making it possible to share or bookmark filtered views.

I'm trying to do that with Next.js 13, so I'm looking to replace react-router-dom with the routing in Next.js. However, I'm not sure how to handle the URL parameters and updating the URL when checkboxes are selected in a Next.js application.

I haven't encountered any specific errors. My issue is in understanding how to achieve the same URL parameter management and checkbox behavior using Next.js.

I tried going throuhg the Next.js documentation, using this link:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params
Though, I am not sure how can translate them in my code.

Answer (score 0):

**You can utilize the built-in routing capabilities of Next.js and modify the code accordingly**

In the below code:

*`useSearchParams` hook is replaced with the `useRouter` hook from Next.js, which provides access to the router object.*

*`useNavigate` function is replaced with the `push method` of the router object to update the URL.*

*`searchParams` object is replaced with `router.query`, which contains the query parameters from the URL.*

*`navigation variable` is replaced with the `router object`.*

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const sexData = [
  { value: "male", name: "Male" },
  { value: "female", name: "Female" },
];

const colorData = [
  { value: "red", name: "Red" },
  { value: "blue", name: "Blue" },
  { value: "green", name: "Green" },
];

const categoryData = [
  { value: "clothing", name: "Clothing" },
  { value: "shoes", name: "Shoes" },
  { value: "accessories", name: "Accessories" },
];

const sizeData = [
  { value: "small", name: "Small" },
  { value: "medium", name: "Medium" },
  { value: "large", name: "Large" },
];

export default function App() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState(() => {
    const initialItems = {
      sex: {},
      colors: {},
      categories: {},
      size: {},
    };
    return initialItems;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentParams = router.query;
    updateSelectedItems(currentParams);
  }, [router.query]);

  const updateSelectedItems = (params) => {
    const newItems = { ...selectedItems };
    for (const key in newItems) {
      if (params[key]) {
        const itemList = params[key].split(",");
        newItems[key] = itemList.reduce((acc, item) => {
          acc[item] = true;
          return acc;
        }, {});
      }
    }
    setSelectedItems(newItems);
  };

  const handleOnChange = (group, value) => {
    const updatedItems = { ...selectedItems };
    if (!updatedItems[group][value]) {
      updatedItems[group][value] = true;
    } else {
      delete updatedItems[group][value];
    }
    setSelectedItems(updatedItems);

    // Update URL params
    const queryParams = Object.entries(updatedItems)
      .filter(([key, value]) => Object.keys(value).length > 0)
      .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${Object.keys(value).join(",")}`)
      .join("&");

    router.push(`/?${queryParams}`);
  };

  const renderList = (group, title, data) => (
    <div className="item-group">
      <h3>Select {title}</h3>
      <ul className="item-list">
        {data.map(({ value, name }, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <div className="item-list-item">
              <div className="left-section">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id={`custom-checkbox-${group}-${index}`}
                  name={name}
                  value={value}
                  checked={selectedItems[group][value] || false}
                  onChange={() => handleOnChange(group, value)}
                />
                <label htmlFor={`custom-checkbox-${group}-${index}`}>{name}</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {renderList("sex", "Sex", sexData)}
      {renderList("colors", "Colors", colorData)}
      {renderList("categories", "Categories", categoryData)}
      {renderList("size", "Size", sizeData)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have one problem, which is:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sex')

Why do you think is that?